# Finding the Number of Business Hours Between Two Date/Times (8am -5pm)

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am using Salesforce and I want to find the difference in hours when a ticket is open and closed/now(when still open). For this case, I am using the following query

```
ROUND( 8 * (
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( ClosedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
    MIN(5, 
     MOD( DATEVALUE(ClosedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7) +
     MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD(ClosedDate  - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 16:00:00' ), 1 ) ) )
    ) 
   )
 -
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
     MIN( 5,
      MOD( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) - DATE( 1996, 1, 1), 7 ) +
      MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD( CreatedDate - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 16:00:00' ), 1) ) )
    )
   ) 
  ), 
0 )
```

Which is [shown here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5)

But I'm getting this error
[image: Salesforce Error]

Is there any other way I can get the difference in dates in the number of hours?

Answer (score 0):

To find the difference for the exact age of a case and compare the opened date with closed date, you should use the following formula:

```
IF( 
ClosedDate - CreatedDate > 0 , 
TEXT( FLOOR( ClosedDate - CreatedDate ) ) & " days " 
& TEXT( FLOOR( MOD( (ClosedDate - CreatedDate ) * 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours " 
& TEXT( ROUND( MOD( (ClosedDate - CreatedDate ) * 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes", 
"" 
)
```

The result of this would be a returned as a `text` that would look like this:

```
6 days 15 hours 45 minutes
```

You can modify this slightly to get the numerical value to use in reports. However, the numbers are going to be in base ten.

In order to factor in the business hours the following formula worked for me:

```
ROUND( 8 * (
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( ClosedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
    MIN(5, 
     MOD( DATEVALUE( ClosedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7) +
     MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD( ClosedDate - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 16:00:00' ), 1 ) ) )
    ) 
   )
 -
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
     MIN( 5,
      MOD( DATEVALUE( CreatedDate ) - DATE( 1996, 1, 1), 7 ) +
      MIN( 1, 24 / 8 * ( MOD( CreatedDate - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 16:00:00' ), 1) ) )
    )
   ) 
  ), 
0 )
```

The result of this would be returned as a `number` that would look like this: `91.00` hours